# Binary Tree Abstraction in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Basic binary tree node in Java can be defined as:

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

But in many situations I need to add fields to tree nodes like size, height, depth, or colour.
If I don't want to rewrite all the definition for left subnode and right subnode and try direct inheritance:

```
public class TreeNodeWithDepth extends TreeNode{
    int depth;
    TreeNodeWithDepth(int val, int depth) {
        super(val);
        this.depth = depth;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work because the left and right of TreeNodeWithDepth are still TreeNode.
Is there a better way to describe this kind of inheritance?

Comment: Are you sure you want attributes such as size, height, and color directly on the tree's nodes? Seems like rather than storing your int val, you should create a wrapper object for all of the attributes you want, then store them inside that object rather than directly on the tree node. (See Alex's answer)

Comment: Java class inheritance: Not even once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't really override member variables, what about using getters, i.e. `getLeft()` and `getRight()` to enforce this since you can make the return types more specific. This fixed it on the consumer side. Those methods might have to cast, though.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use a generic `TreeNode` which can hold watever type of class you need instead. That might look like this:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {
    T val;
    TreeNode<T> left;
    TreeNode<T> right;
    TreeNode(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Then you could create a class to hold the values you need and use that with the `TreeNode`

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this.  Using inheritance to implement `has a` relationships creates all kinds of problems.  There are two approaches:

1. Learn about generics.  See the Java container libraries for examples.
2. Program to an interface.

The interface for a tree node would look like this:

```
interface TreeNode {
  void setLeft(TreeNode node);
  TreeNode getLeft();
  void setRight(TreeNode node);
  TreeNode getRight();
};
```

NB for this particular problem, generics are the conventional choice.